# Reading JPEG2000 without huge memory hit

Tags: java, javax.imageio, jpeg2000

I am using Image to read JPEG2000 images in Java. There appears to be a huge memory whole where everything is held in memory and this is not released. Are there any workarounds to avoid this?

Comment: generally Java loads images as uncompressed bitmaps.  This can increase the size of an image dramatically. How big are your images, even uncompressed I would imagine they would be less than 100 MB each.

Comment: The data is 500,000 bytes. The problem is that ImageIO caches the data in memory so my usage goes from 10M to 130M even after I get rid of the JPeg2000 reader.

Comment: And the cache isn't implemented using weak references? No experience with that library but I'd find that pretty surprising. Maybe you're just not using enough memory for a complete gc run to happen.

Comment: I've run a profiler and the JPEG2000 code loads everything into memory and keeps it :-( when I use ImageIO.read()

Comment: you could try with [jj2000](http://code.google.com/p/jj2000/) instead, it may provide better results